# Hide show toggle fields in html through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, show

```
<form>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="select01">Mode of Test:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="age" name="age" class="form-control">
                        <option value=''> - Select - </option>
                        <option value="14">Online</option>            
                        <option value="13">Written</option>                                 
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="parentPermission" style="display: none">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization" >Venue :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="txtPassportNumber" name="parent_name">                  
            </div>
        </div>                              
        <div class="control-group" id="Permission" style="">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization">Test Link :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="organization" name="organization">                  
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="control-group" id="Permission" style="">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization">Upload Guide Line Document & Instruction Message :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="organization" name="organization">  
                <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>  
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 
    $("#age").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#age").val() <= 13)
        $("#parentPermission").show();
    else
        $("#parentPermission").hide();
}
</script>
```

when i click on ONLINE test link and upload guide should show up and Venue should be hidden. And when I click on Written, Venue should show up and test link & Guide link should be hidden. I tried show hidden toggle method can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is Place your online part of code in a div let us say with id as online and offline part in a div with id as offline.

In the beginning keep nothing selected and then when online is selected show the online div while hiding the offline and when the offline is selected show offline and hide online part.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="select01">Mode of Test:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="testType" name="age" class="form-control">
                        <option value='' selected disabled> - Select - </option>
                        <option value="14">Online</option>            
                        <option value="13">Written</option>                                 
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="offline" style="display: none">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization" >Venue :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="txtPassportNumber" name="parent_name">                  
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="online" style="display:none;">
        <div class="control-group" style="">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization">Test Link :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="organization" name="organization">                  
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="control-group" style="">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization">Upload Guide Line Document & Instruction Message :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="organization" name="organization">  
                <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testType").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#testType").val() == 14)
    {
        $("#offline").hide();
        $("#online").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#online").hide();
        $("#offline").show();
    }
}
</script>
```

A simpler example can be:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="testType">
<option value = "" selected disabled>Select mode</option>
<option value = "online">Online</option>
<option value = "offline">Offline</option>
</select>
<hr/>
<br/>
<div id="online" style="display:none;">I am online part</div>
<br/>
<div id="offline" style="display:none;">I am offline part</div>
<br/>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testType").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#testType").val() == "online")
    {
        $("#offline").hide();
        $("#online").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#online").hide();
        $("#offline").show();
    }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @Scott Marcus You can simply set the callback function as:

```
$("#testType").change(toggleFields);
```

and need not wrap it as an anonymous function.

This would be a more efficient approach.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select id="testType">
    <option value = "" selected disabled>Select mode</option>
    <option value = "online">Online</option>
    <option value = "offline">Offline</option>
    </select>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    <div id="online" style="display:none;">I am online part</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="offline" style="display:none;">I am offline part</div>
    <br/>



    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testType").change(toggleFields);
    });
    function toggleFields() {
        if ($("#testType").val() == "online")
        {
            $("#offline").hide();
            $("#online").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#online").hide();
            $("#offline").show();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap `toggleFields()` in an anonymous function that is being registered as the callback for the `change` event of  the dropdown. Also, it is not a good idea to have a basic `else` condition for the `if` as this won't scale well.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus That is a good and efficient suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show and hide the correct sections not just hide. Also, you have multiple elements with the `id` of `Permission` which isn't correct.

What I've done here is just added `group1` and `group2` classes to the two different sections and then show and hide them accordingly. Initially (via CSS), both sections are set to be hidden.

Also, in hooking up the `toggleFields` event handler, your code wraps the call in an anonymous function, which is not necessary. You also are calling `toggleFields` as soon as the document is ready, which also isn't needed since all the fields will be hidden by default.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#age").on("change", toggleFields);
});

function toggleFields() {
    switch (parseInt($("#age").val())) {
      case 13:
        $(".group1").show();
        $(".group2").hide();
        break;
      case 14:
        $(".group2").show();
        $(".group1").hide();
        break;
    }
}
```

```css
.group1, .group2 {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="select01">Mode of Test:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="age" name="age" class="form-control">
                        <option value=''> - Select - </option>
                        <option value="14">Online</option>            
                        <option value="13">Written</option>                                 
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group group1" id="parentPermission">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization" >Venue :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="txtPassportNumber" name="parent_name">                  
            </div>
        </div>                              
        <div class="control-group group2" id="Permission">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization">Test Link :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="organization" name="organization">                  
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="control-group group2" id="Permission" style="">
            <label class="control-label" for="organization">Upload Guide Line Document & Instruction Message :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="organization" name="organization">  
                <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>  
</form>
```